# How to access properties of an extended class in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript

Good day, i have a class extended as a MovieClip
note: myPiece is a subclass of MovieClip :)

```
package  {

public class Xspy extends myPiece{

    public function Xspy(){
         super("Espy1","Board50");
    }

}}
```

Now added this bunch of code:

```
    protected function setCoor(myX:Number,myY:Number):void{
        this.x=myX;
        this.y=myY;
    }
```

im fully aware that is method is enough to do the job of altering the x and y coordiantes of movie clip but IT ONLY WORKS inside the class definition.

What i want is an external class file to change the x and y property of this class.

PS. i can only think of declaring this function as STATIC to fix this for me. But it is not allowed at AS3

Thank is advance

---

Thanks for that :) It is true that i want an external file to call the setCoor function, setting the access modifier to public still doesnt make my desired result.

correct me if im wrong, but I can only call static methods from one class via an external class. In this case `public function setCoor(myX:Number,myY:Number):void` is not accessible into my other class because it is not static.

Whenever i changed the function as a static one, the error is something like i cannot change the x and y property using a static function. It seems to me that im trying to do something that is not possible using AS3 :) (based on my evaluation only)

---

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Can you clarify what you mean by `external class`?  Also, how many Xspy objects are you planning on instantiating?  Also, if you can share any code regarding this external class, it may help me better understand what you are trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for making things complicated :) By `external class` i simply mean other class apart from the Xspy. So here's some sort of what i want to happen (since my code is to messy already for others to comprehend) :

i have a class xSpy that extends the movie clip class and is link to a movie clip in the stage.

i have another class named Main (note it is not the document class) which is also a class extended as Movie clip and is linked to a movie clip in stage as well.

What I want is the xSpy movieclip to change its coordinate every time i press the Main movieclip xD

Comment: Is this `Main` class you are referring to a static class?

Comment: No its not. Its is just a normal one like this

'public class Main extends MovieClip{...}'

Answer (score 0):

Since Xspy extends myPiece, which extends MovieClip, any class can already change the x and y property of Xspy.

However, if what you meant to type was "I want an external class file to *call the setCoor function* to change the x and y property of this class", then you have to change the function declaration to be `public` instead of `protected` because `protected` functions and variables can only be accessed by subclasses.

```
public function setCoor(myX:Number,myY:Number):void{
    this.x=myX;
    this.y=myY;
}
```

Just a side note, if you are writing this function to simplify lines of code, fine, not something I would do because it's really not necessary and adds a tiny bit of overhead to your application since the x and y properties of the MovieClip class are already public and accessible by anything that has access to the MovieClip.  Now if you plan on performing some extra functionality in the `setCoor` function, this makes sense; however, I wanted to throw out a word of caution about this since the x and y properties are public and if accessed directly, it would be circumventing the functionality you added to the `setCoor` function.